# Running the Nether and Overworld on separate servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to run the Nether and Overworld on separate servers connected via Bungeecord/Waterfall as a workaround for Minecraft's single-threaded performance. I've done this sort of thing before and I've already synced up all the necessary information between servers. This time, I am running into two problems.

1. Nether portals, previously I had predefined portals that would teleport players as soon as they entered a predefined zone, but with nether portals which are always being created and destroyed, I can't do that.
2. I need to calculate where the portals will end up and replicate vanilla portal behavior. I know Java and have some experience with Bukkit/Spigot/Paper but I'm not sure where to start in making a plugin for this.
3. I can't find a way to disable the Overworld on my second server, this can be resolved by teleporting players after they've been sent to the server but it's not an ideal solution and changing the generation to match that of the nether affects the spawning of mobs.

I'm pretty skilled with computers and general and I can do a little bit of Java programming, but don't worry about throwing something a little complicated at me. I just need some solutions and ideas (though I would prefer using already existing software or plugins instead of writing and maintaining my own).
**This is a repost in a different section, as my question(s) don't exactly fall under one category.**

Comment: What do you mean with "repost", "section" and "category"? Where did you post this before? Also, there's a reason why the Minecraft server isn't currently multithreaded: It's very, very complicated. Even if you get this to work, you'll constantly run into more and more edge cases that work differently than you want and that you didn't consider before.

Comment: Fabian Röling, let me simplify. I am not trying to multi-thread Minecraft, that's already been done (https://github.com/MinimallyCorrect/TickThreading & https://github.com/Akarin-project/Akarin). I want to run each Minecraft world on its own separate server and sync up the data via MySQL (something I have already accomplished successfully). The problem I am running into is related to Nether Portals. Their behavior is very specific and I'm looking for a way to replicate them with my current "One server for each world" setup.

Comment: Then you should give a lot more details about your current setup, otherwise it's impossible to tell you what's wrong.